# determination of dimension of some spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I need to compute dimension of polynimials degree at most k such that $P(x) = P(1-x)$ and (it can be done similarly, I belive) such that $P(x) + P(1-x) = 0$.
Also, I suppose it very easy, but I can't compute dimension of arithmetic progression.

Comment: What do you mean saying "dimension"? The dimension of the linear space of polynomials satisfying this relation? This is clearly infinite-dimensional, containing (for the first equation) $\left(x-{1\over 2}\right)^{2n}$ for any $n$.

Comment: Sorry, I forget to write  that degree should be at most k.

Answer (score 2):

If a polynomial satisfies $P(x)=P(1-x)$, consider a translated polynomial $Q(x)=P\left({1\over 2}+x\right)$. Then $$Q(x)=P\left({1\over 2}+x\right)=P\left(1-\left({1\over 2}+x\right)\right)=P\left({1\over 2}-x\right)=Q(-x)$$

Thus, $Q(x)$ is an even polynomial, thus contains only terms of even degree.

The second equation rearranges to $P(x)=-P(1-x)$ and can be dealt with similarly, yielding odd polynomial $Q$.